# Read Write C++ Dynamic Arrays in C# (InteropServices)

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport, dllexport, interopservices

I have a C++ class which has a header(matrixheader.h) such that :

```
#pragma once

class M
{
    public:
        M(int m,int n);
        void MSet(int m,int n,double d);
        double MGet(int m,int n);
        ~M();
    private:
        double** mat;
};
```

Class is defined as follows in (matrixbody.cpp):It is built in Win32 Platform.

```
#pragma once
#include "matrixhead.h"

M::M(int m,int n)
{
  mat = new double*[m];
  for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
  {
    mat[i] = new double[n];
  }
}

void M::MSet(int m,int n,double d)
{
    mat[m][n] = d;
}

double M::MGet(int m,int n)
{
    double d = mat[m][n];
    return d;
}

M::~M()
{
    delete[] mat;
}
```

I have made a wrapper for the Class like so(matrixwrapper.cpp):The wrapper is also built in Win32 platform.

```
#include "matrixhead.h"
#include "matrixbody.cpp"

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void* Make(int m,int n)
{
    M o(m,n);
    return &o;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void setData(void* mp,int m,int n,double d)
{
    M* ap = (M*)mp;
    M a = *ap;
    a.MSet(m,n,d);
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) double getData(void* mp,int m,int n)
{
    M* bp = (M*)mp;
    M b = *bp;
    double d = b.MGet(m,n);
    return d;
}
```

I import the class to C# and try to call the C++ dl methods from C#:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


namespace wrappertest
{
 class Program
   {
    [DllImport("matrixwrapper.dll")]
    unsafe public static extern void* Make(int m,int n);

    [DllImport("matrixwrapper.dll")]
    unsafe public static extern void setData(void* mp,int m, int n,double d);

    [DllImport("matrixwrapper.dll")]
    unsafe public static extern double getData(void* mp,int m, int n);

    static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
    {
        void* p = Make(10, 10);
        setData(p,10,1,10);
        Console.WriteLine(getData(p,10,1));
    }
  }
}
```

But when i try to run the C++ dll methods from C# i get the following error

1//Attempted to read or write protected memory.This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt when running C# code in x64.

2//An attempt was made to load a program with incorrect format when runnning in x86 Active/x86 or in AnyCPU platform.

Questions:

1//What is wrong in the above code ?

2//Considering that my final objective is to make a 2d dynamic array in C++ and read/write data in the array such as the one double**mat in the matrixheader.h file above from C#?is there any other way to implement it ?

Comment: Do you realize that `Make` returns a pointer to the stack? This is *very* bad...

Comment: So how do we fix this? Can you point me towrads an article which explains this error further ?

Comment: You could also make a C++/CLI wrapper instead, and have a more direct and clean usage in C#.

Comment: btw your matrix class leaks memory, please just use `std::vector` instead for dynamic arrays. Or at least make sure you delete all the child arrays as well before deleting the parent. The best choice is just to create the array in C# there is no need for C++ here.

Comment: No need for unsafe here. Element by element access will be slow.

Comment: @Mgetz : i need to create large 2d arrays with 10,000*10,000 elements which for one is not supported in C# arrays and even if i implement via some other collection class manipulating them is very very slow in C# as compared to C++

Comment: @AdityaPatil if you allocate as one m*n C# array it's a) not as slow b) more likely to work c) probably should still be built x64

Comment: @Aditya In C#, `var test = new int[10000 * 10000];` works just fine.

Comment: @AdityaPatil - If you're creating 10000 x 10000 arrays, your matrix creation is horrible as it makes 10,001 calls to `new[]`.  All you need are 2 calls to `new[]` and 2 calls to `delete[]`.  Please see this answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21943621/how-to-create-a-contiguous-2d-array-in-c/21944048#21944048

Comment: @ lucas i tried it out manipulating such as operations for transposing takes around 29secs sometimes, after using Parallel.For in C# and other optimizations down to 1.2 to 3 secs.Can we make it faster if we lets say not allocate data for the array in C# but on the heap in C++ and process it and manipulate it in C++ dll itself and get back the result after a long process of manipulation back to C#?

Comment: @Mgetz: in the matrixheader.h file i mention a ~M(); which is defined as ~M(){delete[] mat;} will this not be called automatically when object M is deleted ? i thought this would not create a memory leak.

Comment: @AdityaPatil - For each call to `new[]`, you need a call to `delete[]`.  Did you read my comment?  You called `new[]` 10,001 times.  So your destructor is not correct -- it leaks memory.  Also, to add to my previous comment, your allocation is not only slow, it is *highly* flawed -- please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27425126/dynamic-allocation-of-two-dimensional-array-c/27425293#27425293

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Yes im looking through the link you mentioned in the above comment.

Comment: @AdityaPatil - I updated my comment to you.  Consider what happens if one of those calls to `new[]` faiils  due to an exception being thrown.  What do you do then?  It is much easier to either use `std::vector` or seriously reduce the number of calls to `new[]` to a minimum amount in case of `new[]` failure.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i understand.I agree using std::vector is better.

Answer (score 1):

Let's get the easy thing first:

> An attempt was made to load a program with incorrect format when runnning in x86 Active/x86 or in AnyCPU platform.

This simply means you have a platform mismatch. You're either trying to load an x86 C++ dll in an x64  .NET runtime, or the reverse.

The following error is the real problem:

> Attempted to read or write protected memory.This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt when running C# code in x64.

That's to be expected, because your `Make` function creates an object on the stack, then returns a pointer to it. By the time you read back this object, the contents on the stack has changed (the stack is being reused), and the `mat` pointer points somewhere else, most probably into unallocated memory.

Please [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27347141/3764814) where I go into deeper detail about this issue (it's C# but it's the same issue).

You have to allocate some dynamic memory to solve your problem. You may try:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void* Make(int m,int n)
{
    M* o = new M(m,n);
    return o;
}
```

And of course, you'll have to create one more method to perform the matching `delete` if you don't want to leak memory.

Also, like Mgetz points out in the comments, you have a memory leak in the `M` class itself. The `delete[] mat;` call in the destructor won't free every allocated chunk of memory. You're calling `new` in the constructor `m + 1` times, this means you have to call `delete[]` `m + 1` times also in the destructor, once for each `new`. You probably should keep `m` and `n` as fields in your class (at least `m` is mandatory to know how many calls to `delete[]` you have to do).

A much better solution would be to use a single array instead of jagged arrays. You calculate the index `i, j` in that array as `i * m + j`. You may also use a `std::vector` or just do it in C# altogether:

```
public class M
{
    private double[] _items;
    private int _m;
    private int _n;

    public M(int m, int n)
    {
        _items = new double[m * n];
        _m = m;
        _n = n;
    }

    public this[int i, int j]
    {
        // Here, you should perform a bounds check on i and j against _m and _n
        get { return _items[i * _m + j]; }
        set { _items[i * _m + j] = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: he doesn't even need the C++, he can just create the whole thing in C# and it will probably be faster than the cost of the interop. If for some reason he does need C++ he should probably just use an m*n length `std::vector` and then index in. Allocating each line of the matrix separately is actually much more expensive and makes indexing into it slower.

Comment: @Mgetz absolutely, I was going to suggest the same thing but you beat me to it ;)

Comment: @Mgetz and Lucas thanks guys i will take up your suggestions and implement them.I knew i could do this the using vector class as Mgetz suggested and flattening the array but i wanted to figure out which method was faster thus the above implementation